# Not sure how to use QtTest

Tags: c++, qt, qttest

I want to do unit testing for some simple exercises i have done in c++ using Qt. i figured using QtTest seemed like a reasonable place to start.

i have a class that returns an integer and i want to test that the expected result is the same as the actual.

am i right in thinking i make a new c++ source file in the project to use as the QtTest

heres what i have but from reading the Qt documentation i cant work out what i have to do?

```
    #include "Conversion.h"
#include <QtTest/QtTest>


class ConversionTest : public QObject
{
private slots:
    void testConvert();

};

void ConversionTest::testConvert()
{
    int unit1 = 1, unit2 = 10;
    std::string sUnit1 = "stone", sUnit2 = "pound";
    double expected = 10.8862;
    double actual;

    Conversion c;
    actual = c.convert(unit1, unit2, sUnit1, sUnit2);
    QCOMPARE(expected, actual);
}

QTEST_MAIN (ConversionTest)
#include "conversiontest.moc"
```

this is what i produced after reading the documentation but now what how do i run it and get the (what i think is) console output that says pass/fail?

any help would be great thanks

Comment: You're missing the Q_OBJECT macro in your class.

Comment: ok added it and no different still no console opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself the problem was just Qt errors no problem with the code at all, for some reason it didnt like that my project files were in a folder structure of more than one folder before my project files, used the exact same code in a new dir and it worked?? :S

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an app with it (`QTEST_MAIN(..)` builds the `main` function for you), and specify `CONFIG += qtestlib` in the `.pro` file.

When you run it, a console opens that prints out the test results.

Comment: sorry dont know what u mean by an app? im new to c++

Comment: I know `QTEST_MAIN` is there, I was just explaining that even though you need to build an executable, you don't need to define a `main(..)` function as the macro does it for you.  An 'app' as in you need to tell `qmake` that you are building an executable (as opposed to a shared library, etc.) - this just involves setting the `TEMPLATE` section to 'app' in the `.pro` file.

Comment: it already is ? and still nothing happens and theres no exe in my source folder either? some sample code would really help me here

Comment: Sample code isn't going to help as we still have no idea what is wrong.  If you have no exe then either compilation is failing or configured wrong.  Update your question with the `.pro` file, and any compiler output.